# How to Configuring ConnectionFactory JMS on JBossAS5?

Tags: java, jms

This is the first my question in this forum.. :)

please help me about how to configuring JMS ConnectionFactory on JBossAS5..
i have created a simple MDB application :

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MessageMDBSample", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/MyQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
```

public class DummyMDBeanBean implements MessageListener {

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

}

How to configure Queue and ConnectionFactory, at this instance queue/MyQueue on JBossAS5?..

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your connection factories and destinations (Queue or Topic) in these files:

messaging/connection-factories-service.xml
messaging/destinations-service.xml

And verify messaging/messaging-service.xml   for any core configuration.

By the way, by default, you can modify the configuration of Hypersonic embedded database that comes with Jboss AS. You can modify/create a connection factory in hsqldb-ds.xml.

In these files, you have samples that you can easily use to create new ones.